# error with MFMailcomposeviewcontroller in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm relatively new to Swift, and need help with this error I keep getting. I'm trying to bring up an email on this view controller, but it keeps giving me the error:

> "attempted to present MFMailcomposeviewcontroller whose view is not in
>   the window Hierarchy".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var pickerview2: UIPickerView!

let reason = ["Busy - General","Filming","Editing","Computer Task","Helping","Getting Set Up"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return reason[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return reason.count
}

@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "reasontosent", sender: self)

    let toRecipients = ["jvfdjnnvf@gmail.com"]

    let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
    mc.setSubject("Media Team Task")

    mc.setMessageBody("Name:  Placeholder", isHTML: false)
    //make it like this: mc.setMessageBody("Name:  \(nameField.text!)", isHTML: <#T##Bool#>)

    controller.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to present/dismiss the `mc` by using `controller`, what is it?

Comment: i used a tutorial, [here](https://youtu.be/Kxs6HF3Ly48), and the end code,

Comment: controller.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil) displays an error, "use of unidentified resolver 'controller'.

Comment: user presentViewController only instead of controller.presentViewController